# Controlling the camera through phone keys

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, camera

I am an android novice. My question is : Is there any free app to take pictures or videos using any phone key, like power or volume up/volume down, without touching the screen button? I checked the other answers here, but they talks about cyanogenmod or a paid app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following Android apps on Google Play

- [DeSpy Camera (Free)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hellosam.despy.free)
- [VolShutter Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beyondweb.rocker.free)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Could you explain why you are recommending these 2 apps. Why not others?

Answer (score 1):

There are many apps. You can go with Vosco which is my favorite one but without key mapping (no hardware button to take pic) but a great one. Otherwise, [Camera360](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vStudio.Android.Camera360) is a good choice. Also you can go with [CameraMx](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magix.camera_mx) (or [Mx Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hd.camera) maybe) or [Line Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.naver.linecamera.android&hl=en) or [Cymera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyworld.camera) (this one has a great range of photo editing tools as well). All of these can be customized to take pictures with volume key or so.

Comment: Vosco? Searching for this on Google Play gives 0 results.

Comment: yes boss! :) Vosco Cam. Recently launched for android.

Comment: I will edit it with the link once I go to home. :)

Comment: @THelper : Think he meant VSCO